# How can I have a basic heading and a custom one?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I have the following CSS to make an `H1` that has a line through the background and it is centered.  I have to use a `span` element between my `h1` tag for it to work.

The CSS is

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family:'Palatino';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight:600;
    color: #2D6A97;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}

h1 span {
    background:#FDFCF8;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1:before {
    background:#E5DEC6;
    content: "";
    display:block;
    height: 1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
}

h1:before {
    left: 0;
}
```

On other pages though, I want just a normal `H1` (without any CSS).

How could I change what I have so that the unstyled `H1` still looks normal?

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
   <h1 class="withborder"><span>Here's my H1</span></h1>
```

Comment: Seems like you answer to your question yourself : you can use a class :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already answered:

- you need to give a class to your `h1`

**But**  if you want to keep your `h1` non-styled then in CSS, you have to apply the styles to the class instead of `h1`, otherwise it will apply to all `h1` you have in your project.

```css
.class {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Palatino';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2D6A97;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.class span {
  background: #FDFCF8;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.class::before {
  background: #E5DEC6;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Here's my H1 non-styled</span></h1>
<h1 class="class"><span>Here's my H1 styled</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are loads of different ways..
Instead of adding classes to every h1 tag though I'd probably 
use a class on the body of the pages I wanted to style the h1 tag with and then target the h1's in the css.

for example

```
<body class="styleThisPage">
```

and in the css

```
 body.styleThisPage h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        font-family:'Palatino';
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight:600;
        color: #2D6A97;
        margin-bottom:60px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
    }

body.styleThisPage h1 span {
    background:#FDFCF8;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

body.styleThisPage h1:before {
    background:#E5DEC6;
    content: "";
    display:block;
    height: 1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:100%;
}



  body.styleThisPage h1:before {
        left: 0;
    }
```

but it's just personal preferences and depends on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that one pages have styled H1 and others does not have it you also can write this styles in file and include this file in pages which need it. Or as was answered before, you can use class for marking your H1 - then you need to write styles for class.